# Controller receives null when posting datetime

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

Situation: I've got an application where I just want to do some CRUD-operations. For example I have a software class which holds Id, Name and an End of Life (EOL) date.

When I want to update a software product the End of Life Property won't get updated. It's always null. I read I should try a custom model binder for date but I couldn't make it work. I use jQuery UI datepicker and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I tried different formats (dd.MM.yyyy, dd/MM/yyyy, ...) but neither of them worked. I also tried to add this in my web.config file (without success):

```cs
<system.web>
    <globalization
       fileEncoding="utf-8"
       requestEncoding="utf-8"
       responseEncoding="utf-8"
       culture="de-DE"
       uiCulture="de-DE"
    />
</system.web>
```

Here is my code:

Sofware.cs:

```cs
public class Software {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? EndOfLife { get; set; }
}
```

SoftwareController.cs:

```cs
// ...
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(Software software)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //....
    }
}
// ...
```

Edit.cshtml

```cs
// ...
  <tr>
     <td>
        <label for="EndOfLife">End of Life</label>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="datetime" id="EndOfLife" value="@software.EndOfLife" class="form-control datepicker">
       </td>
   </tr>
// ...
```

site.js

```cs
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", showWeek: true, firstDay: 1 });
});
```

Comment: why date format inside jquery is "dd/mm/yy" instead of "dd.mm.yyyy" ?

Comment: Must have been a mistake of mine since I was trying out different solutions. It's "dd.mm.yy" right now but it doesn't change anything, still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up the binding. I thought it would use the id instead of the name. After adding the name-attribute in my .cshtml-files everything worked as expected.